# save image data coming from a request using node js

Tags: node.js

I am new to node js.

I wrote a server using node js which will read the request data and save that data into an image file.(Because the data coming is image data itself.)

The node js script I wrote is :

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const server = http.createServer();

server.on('request', function(request, respond) {
    var body = '';
    filePath = '1.jpg';
    request.on('data', function(data) {
        body += data;
    });

    request.on('end', function (){
        fs.appendFile(filePath, body, function() {
            respond.end();
        });
    });
});

server.listen(8080);
```

And from the terminal on same machine , I fired a curl command to send the image :

```
 curl -X POST --data @tmp.jpg 127.0.0.1:8080
```

The tmp.jpg is opening perfectly on my machine.

But 1.jpg (created by node js) is not opening.

What can be the problem ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try to add some debug code (logging), so you can find out whether the function is called at all.

Comment: I tried appendFileSync also , but same problem

Comment: appendFile will append to the existing file with each request. Try using `writeFile` instead.

Comment: What do you mean by **is not opening**? Is it stored? Can you download the file but the browser does not recognize it as jpg?

Comment: I am creating a file locally on my machine and opening it. It is giving me error : No image data

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies with your usage of curl. To send binary data, use the `--data-binary` flag instead:

```
curl -X POST --data-binary @image.jpg 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Also, you need to use `writeFile` instead of `appendFile`. The latter will add each request's data to the same file, which wil not be readable as image.

Furthermore, when processing binary data I find it easier to use buffers instead of string. The request processing would look like this:

```
server.on('request', function(req, respond) {
    filePath = '1.jpg';

    var chunks = []
    req.on('data', d => {
      chunks.push(d)
    })

    req.on('end', function (){
      var data =  Buffer.concat(chunks)      
      fs.writeFile(filePath, data, function() {
        respond.end();
      });
    });
});
```